# Does asyncio support running a subprocess from a non-main thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm developing an application that mainly consists of services which are threads with custom run loops.

One of the services needs to spawn subprocesses and I don't really understand whether it's valid or not. Official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-and-threads) is ambiguous. Namely it says both `asyncio supports running subprocesses from different threads` and `An event loop must run in the main thread` in the same section.

How is it even possible to run subprocess from different threads if event loop must run in the main thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documentation says:

1. You should have running event loop in the main thread.
2. In the main thread please call `asyncio.get_child_watcher()` at the start of the program.

After that you may create subprocess from non-main thread.

**UPD**

Starting from Python 3.8 asyncio has no limitations mentioned above.

Everything *just works*.

Comment: Why do we need this limitation anyway? I would like to avoid occupying main thread, since it's already busy with GUI s event look (Qt).

Comment: When asyncio starts subprocess it need to be notified by subproc finish event.

Unfortunately in Unix systems the generic way to do it is catching SIG_CHLD signal. Python interpreter can process signals only in main thread.

BTW you can try to use [Quamash](https://github.com/harvimt/quamash) for running asyncio eventloop over Qt.

Comment: I will, thank you for suggestion. Wouldn't it possible to make signal catching implicit, without direct requirement of event_loop?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Implicit signal catching cannot be implemented without deep enough asyncio rewriting. Moreover, signals behave like singletons: every part of your program want to have exclusive access to signal system, but libraries may conflict each other.

Comment: What does UPD mean in this case?